# Google Admob ads not showing up in Swift 3 iOS App

Tags: ios, swift3, admob

Hi I have been trying to load Google Admob ads by following this [tutorial](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/display-ads-in-your-application-with-google-admob/) in my Swift 3 app. I did all the steps and my project is running successfully. Here is how I am doing this

```
GoogleBannerView.adUnitID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
GoogleBannerView.rootViewController = self
GoogleBannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

While running the app on simulator, I see nothing. App log is here

[image]

Comment: please add first line from your log into your code request.testdevices = kGADSimulatorID and then you will start seeing ads on simulator

Comment: try run App in real device.

Comment: I think you misplaced the view. You can use the views debugger to see all views frames and check that it is in the correct position with the correct size. Ask for help if you need

Comment: Hey, thanks for the messages, I didn't do anything to the code, and it started working working on real device.